# Qt on Linux - version conflict?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Trying to move a Qt 4.6.3 project from Windows to Debian Linux (Etch). I've installed Qt by downloading the latest version, then running `configure`, then `make install` as root. Yet when I run qmake_qt4 on my project's pri file, here's what I get:

> uic: File generated with too old version of Qt Designer

Running `uic -v` returns 4.2.1. How come? Wasn't `make install` supposed to put the latest Qt on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Qt installs to /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3 and doesn't add it's bin folder to your PATH variable. Also, it's just named qmake.

Either call /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3/bin/qmake using the complete path or add the /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3/bin/ path to your PATH variable and ensure that it is listed there before any other path that may have a qmake. Best thing to do is to uninstall the the debian qt version if you don't need it elsewhere.

Comment: Calling /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3/bin/qmake does the trick. In the future, I'll establish a symlink in /usr/bin or something.